# App runs for a second, and then closes instantly

Tags: ios, xcode

It's a very basic app. When compiling, it shows "Build Successful" ("No issues"). When i click the app icon in the simulator, it runs for a second, and closes automatically. There is no error (say runtime error) i can see. Where should i look for the hint ?

ClickButtonViewController.m file:

```
    #import "ClickButtonViewController.h"

@implementation ClickButtonViewController;



@synthesize decisionText ; 

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender 
{
    decisionText.text = @"Go for it!" ;
}

-(void)dealloc{
    [decisionText release];
    [super dealloc] ; 

}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}




@end
```

ClickButtonViewController.h file :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ClickButtonViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UILabel *decisionText ; 

}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *decisionText ;

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender; 


@end
```

Comment: There are too many things that could cause this. You'll have to show us your code.

Comment: We would need to see code, how do you think the crash is caused?

Comment: ok, added the ClickButtonViewController.h and ClickButtonViewController.m file code. All other code files are automatically created by xcode. So i don't think, i should add them too here.

Answer (score 0):

Build doesn't install the app to simulator, you need to Run the target.

If you have selected not runnable target (such as a static library), Run option will perform the build.